# Word for deliberately taking the literal rather than implied message

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions, phrase-requests

What is the word for understanding someones implied meaning, but being completely pretentious about it and taking their words for what they literally said?

Comment: The habit of "taking their words for what they literally said" is ***literal-mindedness***. The habit of *pretending* to do this, (whilst actually understanding the "implied/intended" meaning perfectly well) could reasonably be called ***pretentiousness***, but a better choice might be [**disingenuous**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/disingenuous) *- pretending to be unaware or unsophisticated; **faux-naïf.***

Comment: This is one of the meanings of _pedantic_.

Answer (score 6):

**"fake or disingenuous literal-mindedness"** as FumbleFingers has mentioned in his comment, seems to be the phrase you're looking for.

> literal-mindedness (noun) the quality or state of tending to take words in their literal sense. [Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/literal-mindedness)

"Most children under the age of five are naturally literal-minded. It takes a crafty adult to fake literal-mindedness."

Comment: Why not *disingenuous* rather than *pretentious*, as also per FumbleFinger's comment. It's more specific than *pretentious*.

Comment: It works, but *disingenuous* is still more specifically about this sort of faking.

Comment: Yes, except your "most children under five" example doesn't exactly match OP's context. Young children usually *don't* really understand metaphorically/idiomatically implied meanings, so they're not *pretending* to be fooled by an irrelevant literal meaning.

Comment: @FumbleFingers  The sentence "most children..." is an example of "literal-minded" not "fake literal-mindedness".  I'm including the later to improve my example.

Comment: Neat edit **:)**

Answer (score 4):

A related word which ODO and OED define as

> Annoyingly unperceptive or slow to understand; stupid; insensitive. Also, of a remark, action, etc.: exhibiting dullness, stupidity or insensitivity; clumsy, unsubtle.

is ***obtuse***.

So when one is deliberately unperceptive, or deliberately clumsy or unsubtle, one is being ***deliberately obtuse***.

Answer (score 0):

"**Work to rule**" or "**white mutiny**" is a form of "**malicious compliance**", in which employees do no more than the minimum required by the rules of their contract, and precisely follow safety or other regulations "**by the book**" or "**to the letter of the law rather than its spirit**" in order to cause a slowdown, rather than to serve their purposes.